# Предпросмотр изображения при загрузке в input type="file"

Tags: jquery, html, css

Пробую сделать предварительный просмотр изображения при загрузке в input `type="file"`
На stackoverflow есть [примеры решения этой задачи](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)
Но у меня код оттуда не работает http://jsfiddle.net/YJG79/9/

```js
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInput").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
.input-file-row-1:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.input-file-row-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
html[xmlns] .input-file-row-1 {
  display: block;
}
* html .input-file-row-1 {
  height: 1%;
}
.upload-file-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 137px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AeUEdJb.png) top center no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.upload-file-container:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.upload-file-container > img {
  width: 93px;
  height: 93px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
.upload-file-container-text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #719d2b;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
}
.upload-file-container-text > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #719d2b;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.upload-file-container input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form name="" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feedback-form-1">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-file-row-1">
      <div class="upload-file-container">
        <img id="image" src="#" alt="" />
        <div class="upload-file-container-text"> <span>Add<br />photo</span>

          <input type="file" name="pic[]" class="photo" id="imgInput" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Помогите разобраться в чем причина.

Comment: @mountpoint большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jquery сбоку на jsfiddle подключи и выставь No wrap - in <body>

http://jsfiddle.net/YJG79/16/ - все работает

[[@Heidel](/users/6360/heidel)](/users/6360/heidel), Вот форма http://rghost.ru/49770076, она работает на всех инпутах, как ты и просил. Я там совсем чуток html изменил и немного чистого js добавил. Немного рагульно получилось, так как на скорую руку делал, но это не сверхважно. Главное разберись с тем кодом. Там все просто.

Comment: Что значит No wrap - in <body> ?

Comment: способ подключения js-кода напрямую в body. В принципе, можете использовать любой способ подключения js-кода. Подробнее об этих способах здесь - http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions

Comment: а правильно подключена, скрипты вызываешь правильно? давай свой код, что на локально на компе вставь в вопрос.

Comment: ну все другое-то что на jquery висит, работает правильно. вот моя форма вся, в архиве, http://rghost.ru/49769092

Comment: ты неправильно кусочек скрипта подключил. вот здесь все работает. если найдешь что я изменил, возьмешь с полки пирожок

Comment: Ага, вижу) спасибо!) а почему нельзя всё в один скрипт запихнуть?

Comment: всмысле не можешь все скрипты что в index.html поместить в один скрипт, например, main.js ?

Comment: Не, почему эти два скрипта если их в один тег script поместить, не работали. И еще такой вопрос, а если нужно сделать такой предпросмотр для нескольких input type="file" что у меня в форме, это для каждого инпута надо своей такой отдельный скрипт написать?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.files[0]) {
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.addEventListener("load", function () {
      document.querySelector("label").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fr.result + ")";
    }, false);

    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  background: silver;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for=pct></label>
<input type=file id=pct>
```

PS: Из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594663/178988

Comment: Можно реализовать для нескольких input-ов? Код выше работает только с первым.