# Предпросмотр нескольких изображений при загрузке в input type=“file”

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как на JS можно реализовать, чтобы я выбрал например n-количество картинок и создались динамические картинки  для предварительного просмотра картинок.

Comment: Ответ есть тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/266125/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-input-type-file

Comment: @Jean-Claude, в этих примерах только одна картинка выводится. А мне нужно чтобы несколько картинок выбираю и несколько предпросмотров было

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал так (можно сразу проверить):

```js
function myFunc(input) {
        
        var files = input.files || input.currentTarget.files;
    
        var reader = [];
        var images = document.getElementById('images');
        var name;
        for (var i in files) {
            if (files.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                name = 'file' + i;
                
                reader[i] = new FileReader();
                reader[i].readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                
                images.innerHTML += '<img id="'+ name +'" src="" />';
                
                (function (name) {
                    reader[i].onload = function (e) {
                        console.log(document.getElementById(name));
                        document.getElementById(name).src = e.target.result;
                    };
                })(name);
                
                
                console.log(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="file" name="files" onChange="myFunc(this)" multiple />
</form>

<div id="images"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  function readURL(input) {
    $(input.files).each(function(i, el) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).appendTo('#im');
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    });
  }

  $("#imgInput").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="bn" id="imgInput" multiple>
<div id="im"></div>
```

Comment: кратко и доступно, спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему.Сколько выбрано файлов, столько и будет создано предпросмотров картинки. 
**CSS**

```
 .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', theFile.name, '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```