# Картинка с типом input="file"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток, есть задача.

Есть картинка(аватарка) при нажатии на неё, нужно вызывать `input="file"` что бы подгружать картинку и менять аватарку, не хочется велосипедить с JS и jQuery может есть другое решение?

Comment: Конечно есть. А Вам надо есть создать? ОК, за Ваши деньги...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если Вам только стилизовать input type=file, то вот, например:

```css
#ava {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/data">
  <label for="ava"><img src="http://zarablegko.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/avatarki.jpg" width="100" /></label>
  <input type="file" id="ava" name="ava" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить аву" />
</form>
```

Но саму загрузку на сервер без php или nodejs реализовать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

По идее, надо загружать на сервер. Но для остального можно использовать что-то такое:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.files[0]) {
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.addEventListener("load", function () {
      document.querySelector("label").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fr.result + ")";
    }, false);

    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: silver;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for=pct></label>
<input type=file id=pct>
```

PS: Этот ответ больше подходит к [другому вопросу](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708673/178988), но поскольку ответ старый и на него есть ссылки извне, удалять его отсюда я не буду.