# Как вывести превью загружаемых картинок через file?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть форма обратной связи, реализована возможность прикрепить несколько изображений. Задача: кликнув по кнопке "добавить", добавлялись изображения и выводились в превью.
Как это реализовать? Знаю что через FileReader, перехватив действие change , но как реализовать - не знаю.

Форма:

```js
document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    f = this;
  evt.preventDefault();
  http.open("POST", "contacts.php", true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText);
      if (http.responseText.indexOf(f.nameFF.value) == 0) { // очистить поле сообщения, если в ответе первым словом будет имя отправителя
        f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value');
        f.messageFF.value = '';
      }
    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
  }
  http.send(new FormData(f));
}, false)
```

```css
#feedback-form {
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
#feedback-form label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  clear: right;
}
#feedback-form .w100 {
  float: right;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 97%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1.5%;
}
#feedback-form .border {
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #C0C0C0 #D9D9D9 #D9D9D9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #abd9f1 #bfe3f7 #bfe3f7;
}
#feedback-form .border:hover {
  border-color: #7eb4ea #97cdea #97cdea;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
#feedback-form .border:not(:focus):not(:hover):valid {
  opacity: .8;
}
#submitFF {
  padding: 2%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) inset;
  background: #669acc;
  color: #fff;
}
#feedback-form br {
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
#submitFF:hover {
  background: #5c90c2;
}
#submitFF:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff, inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="feedback-form">
  <label for="nameFF">Имя:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nameFF" id="nameFF" required placeholder="например, Иван Иванович Иванов" x-autocompletetype="name" class="w100 border">
  <label for="contactFF">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="contactFF" id="contactFF" required placeholder="например, ivan@yandex.ru" x-autocompletetype="email" class="w100 border">
  <label for="fileFF">Прикрепить файл:</label>
  <input type="file" name="fileFF[]" multiple id="fileFF" class="w100">
  <label for="messageFF">Сообщение:</label>
  <textarea name="messageFF" id="messageFF" required rows="5" placeholder="Детали заявки…" class="w100 border"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input value="Отправить" type="submit" id="submitFF">
</form>
```

contacts.php :

```html
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['contactFF'])) {
  $to = "name@yandex.ru"; // поменять на свой электронный адрес
  $from = $_POST['contactFF'];
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "Имя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail: ".$from."\nIP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF'];
  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
  for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
         $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
         $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
         $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
         $message.="

--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
     }
   }
   $message.="
--$boundary--";

  if ($filesize < 10000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594663/178988

Comment: @Александр ты бы вопросы закрывал, которые открываешь :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версия когда больше чем один фаил

```js
   function readURL(input) 
   {
   
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
        {
           for(i=0; i < input.files.length;i++)
           {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
               var oImg=document.createElement("img");
               oImg.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
               document.getElementById("wrapper-img-form").appendChild(oImg);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            //console.log(input.files[i]);
           }   
        }
    }
    
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' multiple id="imgInp" />
       <div id="wrapper-img-form"></div>
    </form>
```

Версия с одним файлом

```js
 function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function(e) {
       $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
     }

     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
 }

 $("#imgInp").change(function() {
   readURL(this);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Comment: А как сделать загрузку и вывод нескольких файлов?

Comment: Это годится на отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @Александр Я добавил в ответ, функцию когда много файлов.

Comment: Супер! Последний вопрос, а как обернуть эти превью в какой-нибудь блок чтобы можно было их стилизовать?

Comment: В какой блок напремер? какой у него ID

Comment: В любой. Например .wrapper-img-form

Comment: Я добавил #wrapper-img-form id в div, теперь все картинки добавляются в него. Смотрите первую версию, с большим количеством файлов