# Делаю превью картинок на JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  var previewWidth = 320, // ширина превью
    previewHeight = 240, // высота превью
    maxFileSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024, // (байт) Максимальный размер файла (2мб)
    selectedFiles = {},// объект, в котором будут храниться выбранные файлы
    queue = [],
    image = new Image(),
    imgLoadHandler,
    isProcessing = false,
    errorMsg, // сообщение об ошибке при валидации файла
    previewPhotoContainer = document.querySelector('#preview-photo'), // контейнер, в котором будут отображаться превью
    modalPhotoContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-preview-photo');
// Когда пользователь выбрал файлы, обрабатываем их
$('input[type=file][id=file]').on('change', function() {
    var newFiles = $(this)[0].files; // массив с выбранными файлами

    for (var i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {

        var file = newFiles[i];

        // В качестве "ключей" в объекте selectedFiles используем названия файлов
        // чтобы пользователь не мог добавлять один и тот же файл
        // Если файл с текущим названием уже существует в массиве, переходим к следующему файлу
        if (selectedFiles[file.name] != undefined) continue;

        // Валидация файлов (проверяем формат и размер)
        if ( errorMsg = validateFile(file) ) {
            alert(errorMsg);
            return;
        }

        // Добавляем файл в объект selectedFiles
        selectedFiles[file.name] = file;
        queue.push(file);

    }

    $(this).val('');
    processQueue(); // запускаем процесс создания миниатюр
});

// Валидация выбранного файла (формат, размер)
var validateFile = function(file)
{
    if ( !file.type.match(/image\/(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)/) ) {
        return 'Фотография должна быть в формате jpg, png или gif';
    }

    if ( file.size > maxFileSize ) {
        return 'Размер фотографии не должен превышать 2 Мб';
    }
};

var listen = function(element, event, fn) {
    return element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
};

// Создание миниатюры
var processQueue = function()
{
    // Миниатюры будут создаваться поочередно
    // чтобы в один момент времени не происходило создание нескольких миниатюр
    // проверяем запущен ли процесс
    if (isProcessing) { return; }

    // Если файлы в очереди закончились, завершаем процесс
    if (queue.length == 0) {
        isProcessing = false;
        return;
    }

    isProcessing = true;

    var file = queue.pop(); // Берем один файл из очереди

    var li = document.createElement('LI');
    var modalLi = document.createElement('LI');
    var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    var modalSpan = document.createElement('SPAN');
    var spanDel = document.createElement('SPAN');
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    span.setAttribute('class', 'img');
    spanDel.setAttribute('class', 'delete');
    spanDel.innerHTML = 'Удалить';

    li.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(spanDel);
    li.setAttribute('data-id', file.name);

    modalLi.appendChild(modalSpan);
    modalLi.appendChild(spanDel);
    modalLi.setAttribute('data-id', file.name);

    image.removeEventListener('load', imgLoadHandler, false);

    // создаем миниатюру
    imgLoadHandler = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
        span.appendChild(canvas);
        modalSpan.appendChild(canvas.cloneNode());
        isProcessing = false;
        setTimeout(processQueue, 200); // запускаем процесс создания миниатюры для следующего изображения
    };
    listen(image, 'load', imgLoadHandler);
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    // Выводим миниатюру в контейнере previewPhotoContainer
    previewPhotoContainer.appendChild(li);
    modalPhotoContainer.appendChild(modalLi);


    // Сохраняем содержимое оригинального файла в base64 в отдельном поле формы
    // чтобы при отправке формы файл был передан на сервер
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    fr.onload = (function (file) {
        return function (e) {
            $('#preview-photo').append(
                '<input type="hidden" name="screenshot[]" value="' + e.target.result + '" data-id="' + file.name+ '">'
            );
        }
    }) (file);
};
```

в previewPhotoContainer превьюшки есть, а вот в modalPhotoContainer рисуется спан такого же размера, но картинки нет, что я забыл?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594663/178988

Comment: Немного не понял как заюзать это в контексте моего кода.