# Возможно ли показать загруженное изображение через js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли показать загруженное изображение в `input[type=file]` через js до сохранения его на сайте?
Как бы предпросмотр изображения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вам нужно вот [это](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/)

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

[Гуглится](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) за 5 секунд

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.files[0]) {
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.addEventListener("load", function () {
      document.querySelector("label").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fr.result + ")";
    }, false);

    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  background: silver;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for=pct></label>
<input type=file id=pct>
```

PS: Из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594663/178988