# Слот для вставки фото в html

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вставить слот, для того что бы на клиентской части при нажатии на этот слот можно было загрузить фото.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Например, `<input type="file" id="photo" accept="image/jpeg"><label for="photo">[ваш нажимаемый блок]</label>` — и далее отправляем как форму, при помощи js или без: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file

Comment: Уже отвечали на этот вопрос вот тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708673/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-js

Comment: Уже отвечали на этот вопрос вот тут:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708673/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-js Разница будет лишь в том, что вам нужно будет в `input` вставить изображение. Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос.