# Предварительная Загрузка изображений на сайт

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery

Есть диалоговое окно, в котором пользователь заполняет текстовую строку и должен подгружать изображение.
Как реализовать загрузку изображения в это диалоговое окно, чтобы пользователь смог удалить или добавить изображение в случае чего. Далее если пользователя все устраивает, он отправляет форму и изображение попадает в основную  БД которое связанно с эти сообщеним. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подобное встречается в социальных сетях и.т.д
Решение ищу на JS , JQuery , PHP.
**Спасибо**

Comment: Добавить туда file upload? В чем конкретная проблема?

Comment: Файлы не должны попадать в основную таблицу с сообщениями, создавать под таблицу с кеш изображениями и в случае отправки пользователем формы, изображения из кеша перемешались в основную таблицу ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Sketch если это форма и в `<input type="file">` было загружено изображение или какой-то другой файл, с ним ничего не нужно делать до отправки формы.

Comment: Дополнил описание.

Comment: Вообще не грузить её на сервер: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594663/178988