# Вставить изображение при загрузке

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

есть инпут

```
<input type="file" name="image" @change="loadAvatar" id="file" class="avtara-in">
```

и метод загрузки фото

```
loadAvatar(event) {
      this.profile.image = event.target.files[0];
      this.profile.avatar = event.target.files[0]['name];
}
```

все работает, но this.profile.avatar присваивает только название, саму фотку не выводит

вот что выводит в консоле

```
File {name: "woomen.png", lastModified: 1565020016089, lastModifiedDate: Mon Aug 05 2019 18:46:56 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 25577, …}
lastModified: 1565020016089
lastModifiedDate: Mon Aug 05 2019 18:46:56 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время) {}
name: "woomen.png"
size: 25577
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
lastModified: (...)
lastModifiedDate: (...)
name: (...)
size: (...)
type: (...)
webkitRelativePath: (...)
constructor: ƒ File()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "File"
get lastModified: ƒ lastModified()
get lastModifiedDate: ƒ lastModifiedDate()
get name: ƒ name()
get webkitRelativePath: ƒ webkitRelativePath()
__proto__: Blob
```

Comment: наверно вам это поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/266125/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-input-type-file

Comment: Более интересно где вывод фото? Его здесь и нет.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял речь идет о реактивности объекта, если да, то то стоит почитать [реактивность во vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

А так пример тут:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    profile: {}
  },
  methods: {
    loadAvatar: function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.files)
      this.$set(this.profile, 'image', e.target.files[0]);
      this.$set(this.profile, 'avatar', e.target.files[0]['name']);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" name="image" @change="loadAvatar" id="file" class="avtara-in">
  <hr>
  profile: {{profile}}
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Vue.js_Logo_2.svg/1200px-Vue.js_Logo_2.svg.png'
  }
})
```

```css
*{
  margin: 10px;
}
img{
  max-width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
}

input{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}


li{
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  Земените ссылку на линк к любой картинке (можно свой):
  <ul>Bот варианты:
  <li>
  https://habrastorage.org/webt/tj/zs/el/tjzseld78ryzmf6-cz2wp69tops.jpeg</li>
  <li>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Vue.js_Logo_2.svg/1200px-Vue.js_Logo_2.svg.png</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" v-model="url"> 
  <img :src="url" alt="image" v-if="url">
</div>
```

Comment: а как подставить в img?

Comment: Да как и обычный img меняйте сорсы, сейчас кину пример второй